# Google Sketchup pro exporter/importer for MD5 model format?

Tags: 3d, models, file-format

Where can I find google sketchup pro MD5 (The doom3 model format) exporter/importer? If there isn't one what modeling program can I use to export/import MD5 models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an MD5 importer/exporter for SketchUp, but you could use [Blender](http://www.blender.org/) along with the MD5 import/export scripts available [here](http://www.katsbits.com/tools/) to convert between MD5 and a format that SketchUp supports.